# Are any changes made to the host Operating System upon installing any package in virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, virtualization

My host OS is windows and I installed CentOS in virtualbox. Will the packages that I install in the virtual box, be accessible/modified in windows?

Answer (score 1):

> Are any changes made to the host Operating System upon installing any package in virtualbox?

No.

> Will the packages that I install in the virtual box, be accessible/modified in windows?

You should also be able to read and write files in the guest file system's disk image from the host system. With the caveat that the guest probably needs to be "off" while you do that, otherwise there is a risk of either corrupting the guest file system or seeing an inconsistent guest file system state from the host.

Installing packages in the guest does not modify the host operating system ... if that is what you were asking.

Comment: That means if I change/update/install any package in windows (ie the host OS), it will be reflected in CentOS but any change/update/install in the packages on CentOS wont be reflected in windows? and that I can still read/writes files (text files) in CentOS from windows but not any package?

Comment: 1) No.  CentOS does not see packages that you install in your Windows system.  And you can't run the CentOS package installer on or from Windows ... because it is not a Windows program. 2)  You can read / write files from Windows **any** files that were installed on the guest  by the guest (see caveat above).  That includes files installed by the guest's package installer.

Comment: These questions you are asking seem to suggest that you don't really understand what virtualization actually does.   I suggest that you go and do some more background reading.

Comment: I understood that I can't run CentOS (ie VM) package installer on or from Windows. Sure will read more on virtualization. Can you suggest some good reading material?